# get specific data from curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to get the value of the variable in the JSON but it keeps on giving me undefined index where the index is definitely there when I open the URL.

Here is my code:

```
 //initializing cURL
            $ch = curl_init();
//setting the URL
            $priceURL = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=570&market_hash_name=Exalted%20Manifold%20Paradox';
//set options
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $priceURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//execute
            $string1 = curl_exec($ch);
//close curl session/free resources
            curl_close ($ch);
//decode the json string into an array
            $json_price_file = json_decode($string1, true);
            $price = $json_price_file ["lowest_price"];
```

It gives an error of Undefined index: lowest_price. However, when you open the URL, the variable is definitely there. What am I missing? Please help :D

Comment: post what does `$string1` have?

Comment: $string1 is just a variable I created there so I can pass it to the json_decode.

Comment: Your code works for me. Please check that you have `php_curl` extension.

Comment: @Wazelin, I do have the extension. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i confirm that your code works well, like Wazelin said, check your php_curl in the php.ini.

**Edit:** after looking at your code (by email) you have to add this :

After you get the `$market_hash_name` value you need to replace the white space by %20 (valid url).

```
$market_hash_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $market_hash_name);
```

Then i advise you to add an condition for the lowest_price to avoid errors :

```
if (isset($json_price_file["lowest_price"])) {
    #your code...
}
```

Regards.

Comment: what value does it give?

Comment: that gives me : $26.16

Comment: can I send you the entire code to your e-mail if thats okay? probably the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yes if you want, email : peacefull@yopmail.com and i will delete it then.

Comment: Hi, I sent to your e-mail.

Comment: I still get Undefined index: lowest_price Error... DO you mind sending the entirety of my code back? Thank you so much